# AnalysisException: Expression not supported within a window function while calculating column value based on previous rows

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have sample data which has 4 fields amt1, amt2, amt3 and amt4. We want to calculate value of amt5 based on sum of fields (amt1, amt2, amt3, amt4) and amt5 value of previous row.

Suppose Below is the dataset:

```
+----+----+----+----+---+
|amt1|amt2|amt3|amt4|ids|
+----+----+----+----+---+
|   1|   2|   3|   4|  1|
|   1|   2|   3|   4|  2|
|   1|   2|   3|   4|  3|
|   1|   2|   3|   4|  4|
|   1|   2|   3|   4|  5|
|   1|   2|   3|   4|  6|
+----+----+----+----+---+
```

Below is the output I am expecting:

```
+----+----+----+----+---+----+
|amt1|amt2|amt3|amt4|ids|amt5|
+----+----+----+----+---+----+
|   1|   2|   3|   4|  1|10  |
|   1|   2|   3|   4|  2|20  |
|   1|   2|   3|   4|  3|30  |
|   1|   2|   3|   4|  4|40  |
+----+----+----+----+---+----+
```

Below are the exception I am getting after execution of above code:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

def sum(*col):
  sum = 0
  for i in col:
    sum = sum + i
  return sum

rdd = sc.parallelize(["1,1,2,3,4", "2,1,2,3,4", "3,1,2,3,4", "4,1,2,3,4", "5,1,2,3,4", "6,1,2,3,4"])
finalRdd = rdd.map(lambda t: t.split(",")).map(lambda t: Row(ids=t[0],amt1=t[1],amt2=t[2],amt3=t[3],amt4=t[4]))
df = spark.createDataFrame(finalRdd)

w = Window.orderBy("ids").rowsBetween(
    Window.unboundedPreceding,  # Take all rows from the beginning of frame
    Window.currentRow)          # To current row

df1 = df.withColumn("amt5",sum(df.amt1,df.amt2,df.amt3,df.amt4))
df1.withColumn("amt5",sum(df1.amt5).over(w)).show()
```

> Below are the exception I am getting after execution of above code:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o121.withColumn.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Expression '(amt5#11 + cast(0 as double))' not supported within a window function.;;
Project [amt1#0, amt2#1, amt3#2, amt4#3, ids#4, amt5#11, total#19]
+- Project [amt1#0, amt2#1, amt3#2, amt4#3, ids#4, amt5#11, total#19, total#19]
   +- Window [(amt5#11 + cast(0 as double)) windowspecdefinition(ids#4 ASC NULLS FIRST, ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS total#19], [ids#4 ASC NULLS FIRST]
      +- Project [amt1#0, amt2#1, amt3#2, amt4#3, ids#4, amt5#11]
         +- Project [amt1#0, amt2#1, amt3#2, amt4#3, ids#4, ((((cast(amt1#0 as double) + cast(0 as double)) + cast(amt2#1 as double)) + cast(amt3#2 as double)) + cast(amt4#3 as double)) AS amt5#11]
            +- LogicalRDD [amt1#0, amt2#1, amt3#2, amt4#3, ids#4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing a collision in the `sum` function. The window function should be from the `pyspark.sql.functions` package, so you should call it as follows:

```
df1.withColumn("amt5",func.sum(df1.amt5).over(w)).show()
```